# multi threaded servlet; single threaded ejb

Tags: java, servlets, ejb

In a traditional n tier web app with servlets for web layer and ejbs(2.0) for biz layer, what is the rationale behind making the servlet model multi threaded and the ejb model single threaded?
 i.e there is only 1 servlet instance for all requests, but for ejbs, for each request, there is a new bean instance assigned from the bean pool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed only one instance for a specific `Servlet` since they are supposed to be stateless. In practice this isn't always the case, but so be it.

There are however multiple instances of `Stateless session beans` (SLSB), and those are pooled.

By their very definition, `stateless session beans` are stateless, so on the surface this *seems* like a paradox. The things is that while `stateless session beans` are stateless with respect to individual calls being made to them, they in fact very often have state.

This state is in the form of *references to other resources*. The `JPA entity manager`, which is **not** thread-safe, is a prime example here. During a single call to a `stateless session bean`, the caller must have exclusive access to this resource. When the call returns, the next caller can have exclusive access, etc.

If a single instance was used, then either all callers would have to wait on each other (which is of course killing for performance), or they would have the access this single instance concurrently. In the latter case, the bean implementor has to do manual locking of the non thread-safe resources like the `entity manager` which is often brittle, error-prone and in the end still causes callers to wait on each other.

So, in order to improve performance and still have the safety guarantee, multiple instances are being used.

Those instances are then being pooled and re-used instead of created fresh for each request, because finding, initializing and injecting all required dependencies of the bean can potentially be time consuming.

All of this thus automatically also means that if you inject an entity manager or other non thread-safe resource into a Servlet (which is allowed), you may run into problems. This is a small loop-hole in the Java EE architecture, which is of course easily worked around by simply making use of stateless session beans.

Comment: Thanks very much! So technically, if the SLSB is not accessing EntityManager, then it can be multi threaded(i.e. only 1 instance)?

Comment: More or less. If this was the case however, you would **not** use the @Stateless annotation, but the @Singleton. Then there is only 1 instance of your EJB bean. You can control with additional annotations whether multiple threads are allowed to access such an EJB simultaneously (as in a regular Servlet) or have to wait on one another (as-if methods where synchronized).

Answer (score 0):

I think that typically servlets present thin facade to the heavy logic implemented in EJBs. Servlets should be stateless and therefore there is no reason to create more than one instance of the same servlet.

If you are using stateless beans only I think that there is no reason to have more than one instance too. But statefull EJBs have state and therefore you need instance per simultaneous request.

I hope I did not say bullshit.

Comment: SLSB have more than one instance per JVM..The num of instances is configured in bean pool